# App crashes due to out of memory exception at setCotentView(R.layout_file_name) line

Tags: android, android-layout, error-handling, runtime-error

Its giving out of memory error at-

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

The error log is-

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=5.0 
APP_VERSION_NAME=1.0
BRAND=samsung
PHONE_MODEL=SM-G900H
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 944652 byte allocation with 751892 free bytes and 734KB until OOM
...........................
```

And sometime also giving binary xml error while inflating at same line.
And the error is ocassional not getting every time I run the code.
Anyone seen that too or know about the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Educated guess: You have a huge image as background in your layout.

Comment: Easy way is to put largeHeap=true in your manifest, but above comment is probably right.

Comment: @laalto, I am also thinking this but how can we fix it because that image is very important.

Comment: @Nanoc, but I have read that is not good practice for using it to tackle out of memory errors.

Comment: Maybe some years ago that had more sense, but now with phones with more RAM than my PC its not so critical. Anyway the android app heap limit is way low.

Comment: @GurvinderSingh If only the content is important and not the quality, try compressing the image and then using it

Comment: It is still critical Nanoc, it's still mobile dev and theres more memory but more apps than ever usign that memory

Comment: @AswinPJ, can we compress images that we set in xml file. Or I have to set that image programatically to compress it?

Comment: What size in pixels does that image has? It does not make sense to use an image with more pixels than the actual device, that why you have the resources folder with different densities or sizes to set your images accordingly.

Comment: @GurvinderSingh Just compress the image using some image manipulation tool. Or use an online image compression tool. It will compress the image automatically for you according to your specifications. Then add the image into your res/drawable and continue.

Comment: @GurvinderSingh What is the size of the image?

Comment: @Goofyahead, the size for hdpi is 480*720 and xxhdpi it is 960*1,440.

Comment: @KNeerajLal, the size for hdpi is 480*720 and xxhdpi it is 960*1,440.

Comment: could you post the layout xml file? also the rest of the code of the OnCreate? because with an image of that size it sound like that shouldn't be the issue... And also the png size that you have in your resource folder.

Comment: @GurvinderSingh I mean the actual size in KB?

Comment: @KNeerajLal, its 550 kb

Comment: @GurvinderSingh Do you have a `drawable-nodpi` folder?

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal, no I don't have such folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the comments suggested its an issue with the size of the image you are loading.

First only use an image as a resource of the size of the screen you are targeting, then use the resource folders with different densities and sizes to give to each device its proper image. (HDPI, XHDPI, ETC)

Also take in consideration that the memory allocation is related with the power of 2 of the bitmap, so maybe a slightly smaller size makes a big difference, you can use something like this with BitmapFactory to test and try out.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
```

}

from android doc handling bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems you have a large background image so you need to take a couple of steps to reduce the memory requirement.

Start by compressing the image (for example with Photoshop's Export For Web option).

It's probably wise to make the exported image a JPG if it is a PNG with transparency or alpha as this information is not required for a background.

Once you have the compressed size image make sure you are using a version suitable for your device - don't make a single large image thats big enough for your bigest target device, but also make smaller versions for lower spec devices which you need to place in drawable folders specific to the device group.

You can see the groups on the [Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation, but the folders you will need are

- `res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png`         // bitmap for medium-density
- `res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png`         // bitmap for high-density (about  480*720)
- `res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png`        // bitmap for extra-high-density
- `res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png`       // (about 960 * 1,440 according to [Gurvinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082923/gurvinder-singh)s comment)